# MVC 5 Dropdown menu with search functionality

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@Html.DropDownList("Values","Add")
```

Using a DropDownList is pretty simple. However, I have a lot of values and having the user manually scroll through it really isn't optimal. How can I add a search function/box (so a user can type what he's looking for and the dropdownlist gets updated accordingly) in MVC5? Once an item is clicked it will be added to a table.

Comment: You will need to find a suitable jquery plugin (for example [jQuery-ui autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) but there are numerous others

Comment: Thank you, seems exactly what I need. :)